# ANTLR 4 : Missing Input Interpreter in eclipse ANTL4 plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr4

In ANTLR IDE plugin of Eclipse , there was an interpreter view in which we could test theinput and it would create a tree structure. like this,

[image]

I couldn't find it in ANTLR 4 plugin of eclipse.

How can I launch it in ANTLR 4 plugin for eclipse Luna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

To create parse tree view go to: Window > Show View > Other > ANTLR> and select parse tree.
click any of the rule that you want to test in your ANTLR editor and enter the input.

[image]